# How to customize semicolon help for TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I would like to know if it's possible to customize the way IntelliJ highlights the line endings in TypeScript files where a semicolon is 'missing'. It appears to highlight that space everywhere where the next line is another statement. From what I understand, as long as the next statement does not start with [ or (, and our team does not put newlines in stupid places like directly after return, continue etc, there is no pain.

I'm talking about the highlight that looks like [image: this].

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to control this.

- Put the cursor on the place where Intellij highlights the missing semicolon. Click the "lightbulb" icon that should then pop up (or Alt-Enter keyboard shortcut for me), you'll see "Terminate statement".  Click the right arrow on keyboard which will open that menu item, click on "Disable inspection"
- Open Intellij Preferences.  Search for "unterminated statement".  You'll find it under Editor->Inspections -> Javascript->Code style issues->Unterminated statement.  Uncheck its checkbox.